# Install Python 3.7+ in Yocto image via command line on runtime

Tags: yocto

I need to run Python 3.7 or higher on a yocto image containing a special piece of software (that needs to be tested) for a CI/CD Pipeline. The problem is, I am not the creator of the image, and I cannot change or edit the layers or include Python at image build time. All tutorials I could find only cover installing it when creating the image. The Python version preinstalled is only Python 2, which is not sufficient.

Is there any way to install Python 3.7+ with a package manager, via the command line on the running yocto image?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to know what package manager it uses (e.g. opkg, dpkg, rpm), and possibly also the Yocto version. You can build the package yourself, transfer it to the running image e.g. with scp, and install with its package manager. You will need to make your Yocto config at least similar to what is used to build the image. (Ignoring the fact that you can't change the layers, do you have access to the layer used to build the image? That would make it trivial)